# Antd Modal, clicking on Mask to not do anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

So by default, Antd Modal will trigger the onCancel property of Modal when the user clicks on the mask(area outside the modal).

But what i want is the program to not trigger anything when the user click mask (just close the modal and not change anything), because i have my own function in the onCancel. How do i make it so? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its so easy, you can delete onCancel line on your modal :D

```js
      <Modal
          title="Basic Modal"
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onOk={this.handleOk}
          //onCancel={this.handleCancel}
        >
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
       </Modal>
```

Answer (score 11):

Set maskClosable prop to false. Documentation page; https://ant.design/components/modal/

Comment: setting maskClosable to false will make the modal cannot be closed when clicking the mask. what i want to do is making it closable by clicking the mask, and do a blank function, not triggering the onCancel prop

Comment: hmm, if it meets your need, you can disable default footer by giving footer prop null and by putting your own cancel button in which you can give a different onClick function then onCancel prop of Modal. But the close icon 'x' and click on mask will trigger onCancel function.

Comment: oppsite to op's request, helpless.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to keep control with the available buttons ( cancel and ok ) and prevent any actions when clicking the mask using maskClosable={false}.

```
<Modal
      title="Basic Modal"
      visible={this.state.visible}
      onOk={this.handleOk}
      onCancel={this.handleCancel}
      maskClosable={false}
    >
      <p>Some contents...</p>
      <p>Some contents...</p>
      <p>Some contents...</p>
</Modal>
```

Now clicking outside the modal window won't trigger anything.